# onchange="#{rich:component('ds')}.switchToPage(this.value)"> in richfaces

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to add a event handler after the switchToPage is finished.
I tried

`onchange="#{rich:component('ds')}.switchToPage(this.value);formatAllRec();">`

but the problem is, formatAllRec will execute before switchToPage is actually finished.
How can I add a event handler and make sure it will execute after the completion of switchToPage?

Comment: call formatAllRec() inside the switchToPage(): on the last line  or inside a callback function if you are using it

Answer (score 1):

> *but the problem is, formatAllRec will execute before switchToPage is actually finished*

This is actually not true. They are executed in order. The symptoms indicate that the `switchToPage()` is in turn firing an asynchronous HTTP request to do some job and returning immediately after sending the request instead of waiting for it to finish.

Depending on the way how you're sending the asynchronous request, there are basically 2 ways to fix it:

1. Make it non-asynchronous. jQuery [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and all its subfunctions such as [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for example have an `async: false` option for this.
2. Invoke `formatAllRec()` as a callback of that asynchronous request. jQuery [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for example can take a callback function as 2nd/3rd method argument.

A more detailed answer with code examples can't be given as you didn't post any JS code. This problem is at least not related to Java/JSP/JSF/RichFaces, but just to plain JS.

Comment: Thanks ! how can I add a event handler to switchToPage ?

Comment: As said, that depends on the way how you're sending the asynchronous request. A more detailed answer can't be given as long as you don't post the relevant JS code responsible for the job.